# How feasible is a nuclear powered air liner?

Tags: internal-consistency

I am envisioning a beautiful world in the near future, say in the next decade. We will have a couple of self sustaining, colossal airplanes, capable of carrying thousands of people and stay airborne for several months without landing to refuel.

These planes will house an efficient and reliable nuclear reactor(s) and acts like a tiny city in the air.

We currently have a few aircraft carriers operating using the principle of  nuclear fission.

Is it feasible to see a flying city, running on nuclear energy, in 10 years time?

Comment: In order to be worth developing, these flying cities would need a purpose, what is that? Also what about the massive risks from a crash?

Comment: And also massive risk from nuclear explosion ! As for the why, the land may be flooded ! What about Zeppelins ? Do you really need nuclear powered aircraft ?

Comment: Nuclear reactors are not inherently that dangerous, in both Chernobyl and Fukushima it was the money it would have required to make them safe that was the issue. So I agree with @SteveBird, safe airborne reactors would be expensive and would need a very good reason to exist. The raison d'etre for the flying cities is also crucial to the question in other ways (it has huge impact on design), you should edit it in.

Comment: Might be a requirement once the ice caps all melt and the declining available land mass forces a population migration, but I agree with Kii that requiring such a vessel to also have the aeronautical properties to achieve flight seems unneccessary. Still, nuke power to keep a giant blimp going might be arguable.

Comment: If you're asking about "our" world, then -- no. "Endless" flying planes, you're talking about, are -- as far as I know -- 100% solar-powered and I have never heard anything about powering them through nuclear fusion (for the reasons already mentioned in other comments). Yet, I heard a lot about about solar power. If you are asking about hypothetical world, then anything is possible, taking "their" development, history, point of view on pollution etc. etc.

Comment: @Kii If the land is sufficiently flooded for this to be a problem, then I think I rather would be aboard a seafaring vessel than an airplane!

Comment: I see no one has yet mentioned [the X-6 project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_X-6) with the [NB-36H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_NB-36H) with a nuclear reactor onboard. It didn't actually power anything onboard, and obviously the program didn't end up in production, so the answers here are pretty valid.

Comment: There are nuclear-powered submarines, so I don't see why not.

Comment: If you are looking for a reference, try Nuclear Materials & Propulsion Operation at http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19640019868.pdf

Comment: Are you talking about an aerostat or an aerodyne?

Comment: For all conventional large scale nuclear reactors, cooling is a big issue - most of energy is not useful, but waste heat, and both nuclear power plants and nuclear ships generally use huge bodies of water as their heatsinks - putting a similar size and power vessel up in the air wouldn't be able to remove as much heat as is needed to keep the reactor running.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your description seems to match a flying aircraft carrier in terms of size, etc. So I will consider it to be a flying version of the [next generation USS Enterprise named PCU Enterprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28CVN-80%29) that is also scheduled to be put into service 10 years from now. Those that like Marvel Comics may envision this as a real life helicarrier. Let's call it the MC1.

The PCU has a loaded draft weight of 100,000 metric tons (including 2 nuclear power plants). A 747 has a loaded capacity of about 450 metric tons. This means that the the MC1 is about 222 times as heavy as a loaded 747.

There are a couple of real problems that are unlikely to be resolved and put into production within 10 years. [Nuclear powered planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Nuclear_Propulsion) have been considered in the past.

**Pressurized Water Nuclear plants are very heavy**: Nuke plants usually require shielding, cooling systems if you don't want to kill everybody. Pressured water plants require high pressure systems, and really should have a containment vessel. There are designs that do not use high-pressure steam, notably liquid metal cooled reactors, gas cooled reactors and liquid salt reactors -- all of these have been considered for use in planes. The liquid metal reactors have additional concerns (esp. toxicity and/or flammability). Most of our experience is with pressurized water plants, so you would be stuck using designs that are not as well understood. Even unconventional designs will be quite heavy so that your available living area will be limited. For military use, these were considerable acceptable as keep bombers in near continuous flight was thought to be worth the compromises required.

A 747 uses about 90 MW for takeoff and 45 MW for cruising. Since the MC1 is 222 times the weight, we will assume that we need 222 times the power which is 20 GW of power. Modern power plants are often in the 1-2 GW range. Now image flying 10 2 GW power plants, or just for cruising 5 2 GW plants. 2 GW plants are more powerful than the 1.5 GM plants used in the Enterprise and much more powerful then the 550MW plants used in the previous generation that is in current use.

**You can't design and build something that large and complicated in 10 years**. Remember the PCU Enterprise, it is scheduled to be ready in 10 years. This will be the 3rd USS Enterprise aircraft carrier, it is another Gerald Ford class design. Yet given all of that experience, the navy will be waiting 10 years for a delivered ship. The MC1 will be more complex, require a new design, have more stringent safety, reliability, and weight issues and will not be ready in 10 years.

You can't even build 10 2-GW nuke plants in 10 years as you really need new design and construction techniques to be lower weight, etc for use on the MC1. Unlike pressurized water plants, we don't have multiple generations of improvements that would make off-the-shelf technology acceptable.

**Reliability cannot be guaranteed** Large projects must be built based on previous experience. Consider the history of off-shore oil rigs. There have been many generations of rigs incorporating new design features (and learning from prior disasters) since the first ones were built. The MC1 is far larger and more complex than the largest offshore rig. Surprisingly [the first marine oil rig was in 1891 and there was a related patent in 1869.](http://aoghs.org/offshore-history/offshore-oil-history/)

Nuclear reactors do not operate 24x7x365. The best uptime is around 96% and includes scheduled and unscheduled downtime. You need lots of redundancy to keep machinery working for months on end. In the case of the nuke plants, 10 plants is clearly redundant when cruising, but what other critical points of failure could be hiding in the MC1?

**Cost** Somebody has to pay for all of this. Since the PCU costs perhaps $10 billion, how much will the MC1 cost, 20, 50, 100, 1000 billion? Design phase costs alone for something this complex could exceed the cost of construction.

**Safety** Not many people are likely to want the MC1 flying overhead as the consequences of falling out of the sky would be horrible. Maybe not too many people, esp. really really rich people, are going to willing to risk flying on it either.

Flying nuke plants do not exactly inspire confidence either.

Clearly a flying city will not need all the military toys found on a carrier, but residents are going to want tennis courts, swimming pools, shopping and fine dining, etc. in the end, I suspect similar weight requirements. A carrier has often been described as a floating city for good reasons.

---

In the event of a serious problem with a nuclear reactor, the MC1 is going to be grounded for a long time. This additional economic risk will also scare of potential investors.

---

Lifting area -- common rule of thumb for winged aircraft is 1000 Newtons per sq. meter, 1000 Newtons is roughly 100 kg, so the lifting surface will need to be 1 million square meters at a minimum. The PCU has a length of 337 meters and a beam of 41 meters, so the total lifting area would be about 13,817 -- you need 72 times as much lifting area. Trying to increase the lifting area would require lots of additional structure to support the lifting area -- Seems like a problem and this is the most energy efficient heavier than air lifting.

Any other ways to generate lift? Rotors have been mentioned and also mentioned as impractical. Jet engines do achieve thrust / weight ratios in excess of 1. [Pratt & Whitney F119](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_F119) have a thrust/weight ratio greater than 9:1, so technically it is possible -- this is an afterburner engine design sans afterburner, and eats fuel at about 14,000 kg/hr to generate 156,000 N (35,000 lbs) of thrust. High tech (expensive) materials will be required in abundance, and frequent and expensive maintenance would also be needed.

Just how much power to operate direct thrust with jet engines? Jet fuel energy  density is about 42.7 MJ/kg and 3600 secs/hr. Burning 14,000 kg/hr means 4.27e7 * 14000 / 3600 = 5.72e7 J/s aka 77.2 MW. To lift the MC1 we need 6292 of these engines. This corresponds to 485.7 GW of power; of course this is only a crude approximation since heating the air with a nuke plant is not the same as heating it by burning jet fuel.

BTW, one of these engines cost 10 million. I am sure that in volume you would get a discount. Since the undiscounted cost would be 63 billion, you are going to want a discount. Even with cash up front, Pratt and Whitney would be very hard pressed to build 6300 of these in 10 years. They only made 507 of these, ever. You might be paying extra for a rush job, maybe $63 billion won't be enough. These engines have also failed in the past, serious fan blade flying through the casing wall, ground your MC1 for a long time failures.

I suppose you could use enough balloons to generate lift, though this would not actually be flying. Just considering the lift of the helium (without airframe, etc.) you can get a lift of about 1 kg / cubic meter of helium. So you will need over 100 million feet of helium. But I don't know that you would be allowed to buy that much as the US helium reserves are about 1 billion cubic meters. Helium cost is about $2.24 per cubic meter so you need a quarter billion dollars worth of helium, at a minimum such as large order would increase the price by a lot. Hydrogen is considerably cheaper, more available, and provides a little more lift. But ever since the Hindenburg, hydrogen is not favored choice for passenger use.

It's only easy in the movies.

Comment: Then there's the other question: Where is the 100,000+ metric tons of atmospheric down-force produced *going*?  That is way more than enough to flatten birds, other aircraft, vehicles and even substantial structures from a considerable distance.  Take-offs and landings would require an exceptional amount of clear land beneath them.

Comment: That's actually a shockingly small amount of helium

Comment: "The PCU has a loaded draft weight of 100,000 metric tons (including 2 nuclear power plants). A 747 has a loaded capacity of about 82 metric tons." I don't know what you mean by "loaded capacity" but the maximum take-off weight of a 747-800 is nearly 450 tonnes. If by "loaded capacity", you mean "cargo capacity", I don't understand why you're comparing the cargo capacity of a plane with the displacement of a ship, which makes no sense.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - http://amasci.com/wing/lasrWing.gif

Comment: @SteveV. yes, exactly what I was referring to.  For something this heavy, the wing-vortices would become microbursts at the least, and maybe even tornadoes at the worst.

Comment: Sorry, looked up the wrong value, clearly by loaded capacity I should have used 450 tonnes. Will fixup answer. Don't think it really changes much of anything as the flying solution that corresponds to a jumbo jet is clearly impractical anyway.

Comment: Good analysis overall, but presuming that the MC1 would way as much as an aircraft carrier is silly. Aircraft carriers are heavily armored and have large, heavy flight decks. An aluminum frame and body with carbon fiber and other composite types could bring the weight down considerably, possibly a factor of ten even with the reactors. That said, anything short of a factor of 100 would not make any difference to your conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

The question is multifaceted, and any definite answer is going to draw on multiple disciplines.

A part of the answer lies in the comment raised by [Steve Bird](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11711/steve-bird): what would be the purpose of such a machine? Who is the intended target audience? Without an answer to this, it becomes very hard to see why something like what you are describing would be developed at all, and even with it, whether it actually does get developed depends very much on the specifics of the answer to that.

A part of the answer will be the time needed to develop a new (*any* new) aircraft. Based on the answer to [How long does it take Boeing to develop an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12283/753) on [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), given that such an aircraft would be a significant change compared to current models, we can likely reasonably expect this to be at a *minimum about ten years* from announcement to first flight.

A part of the answer would be the time needed to develop a safe and suitably lightweight nuclear reactor. Remember that most nuclear reactor power plants work by [heating water, then using the steam to drive a turbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_reactor#Electrical_power_generation) to generate electricity. So you need the reactor, and enough water to bring to a boil to run a turbine in a suitably closed system. You also need the closed system itself, or you would need to add water often. (Note that nuclear reactors are often built close to the coast for reasons of ready access to water, including for cooling purposes.) I'm not sure how feasible a completely closed system nuclear reactor for generating electricity would be. The nuclear reactor would also need to be able to survive a crash without breaching, because, as we know, airplanes occasionally do crash for a wide variety of reasons.

A part of the answer would be that you need engines that are sufficiently powerful to propell the aircraft, which are made to run on electricity, and which are ideally quiet enough that the resultant onboard noise level is not a major problem. Propeller engines can easily be made to run on electricity, but perform poorly at high altitudes and high speeds as well as that they are quite noisy (propeller tip speed is actually [a limiting factor](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/4954/753) in what can be done with propeller engines on aircraft). I'm not sure about the feasibility of an electric jet-type engine, but that may be a good question on Aviation.

A part of the answer is what I alluded to above, crashes. Anyone who proposes something like this has to show that the machine is sufficiently safe. That is going to present a major hurdle in selling the concept to the general public, at the very least, even if cost of living aboard something like it isn't.

A part of the answer will be making it self-sustaining in terms of eatable food and drinkable water. Without self-sustenance, you are going to have to land periodically anyway to take aboard supplies.

But let's say some existing aircraft manufacturer was really bent on producing something like what you are describing. You have given them a ten-year time frame. Is it feasible? Based on the relatively incremental adjustments made for example in the Boeing 787 taking almost nine years from announcement to first public flight (and there probably being some preparatory studies and possibly design work done before the announcement), I would consider the feasibility of a completely new type of airborne platform, with completely different engine technology to what we are using today, to be **very slim.** You are changing too much, and doing it too fast.

**Given a good answer to the question about purpose, with the above difficulties accounted for, a timeframe of 20-30 years might be more reasonable,** assuming that the desire from all involved parties to do something like what you describe is there. If that desire isn't there, I don't see what you describe being developed; there are simply too many problems that would have to be addressed, and which can be adequately addressed by other technologies in any scenario at least I can reasonably see developing in the next decade (and even more so if the scenario develops in such a way that we still have time to design and build *anything* like what you are proposing).

Even when [Kennedy announced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy#Space_policy) the US goal of getting to the moon within about nine years, rocket technology and even rudimentary spaceflight was a reasonably well understood field. Sure there was a lot of work yet to be done in order to land a man on the moon, but much of the theoretical and practical ground work had been done already. And even then it took almost a decade; more than a decade before the technology worked well enough to be considered reasonably reliable in terms of being able to carry out the mission without any major hitches. The Space Shuttle [built on work done in the late 1960s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle#Early_history), [officially began](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_program) in 1972 and first flew in 1981.

Comment: Actually, jet engines running directly on the heat of a nuclear reactor were designed back when nuclear power was **known for sure** to be safe. LOL So you do not probably need a separate power generation and cooling systems. Then again IIRC the programs were cancelled just before actual test flights due to development of ICBM removing the perceived need for bombers staying airborne for extended periods. So it might not work in practice.

Comment: @VilleNiemi It was called "Project Pluto" - development of the nuclear ramjet engine : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Pluto

Comment: @J... No, that is certainly relevant, so a good find, but it isn't what I was talking about.

Comment: The Kennedy moon launch speech, May 25 1961, the Apollo 1 launch date, Feb 21, 1967 -- so less than 6 years to design and launch a Saturn 1, a very complicated system. The fact that it was a flaming disaster is a cautionary tale for rushing into big projects. And, it was not safe and reliable in about a decade. Re: Apollo 11, Neil Armstrong thought chance of success was only 50%, Buzz Aldrin was even more pessimistic, Apollo 13 at best a near miss. Look at the shuttle failure rate -- very complex systems are hard to get right even with rigid standards and extensive testing.

Comment: @GaryWalker Apollo 1 failed during the plugs-out test; that hardly counts as a launch. Apollo 13 was a result of mishandling of the oxygen tank, followed by the consequences of a failure of communication (change of heater voltage) and failure of monitoring (nobody noticed that the tank heater wasn't switching off during the oxygen boil-off). Apollo 17, just three years after Apollo 11 and 11½ years after Kennedy's speech, was a nearly flawless mission to land people on the Moon, extended stay and sample return. There's a reason why most people remember 11 and 13 rather than 7 and 17.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No**.

More useful answer(s):

- It took 5.5 years for the Boeing 777 to go from design phase to the first commercial flight.  This was a new design, but was essentially only a bigger, better version of what they already built.
- Currently, it takes an estimated 9 years for a nuclear plant to go from application process to being built.  Actual building time is 4 years, with an additional 1.5 years pre-construction preparation.  Getting a permit for a plant that could potentially be flying over heavily populated areas will be extremely unlikely.
- Regulations require planes (perhaps only on ocean crossings?) to always be within 3 hours of a diversionary airport.  This plane will require rebuilt airports to have runways sturdy enough to support its weight, and to have enough wing clearance.
- Building new Aircraft Carriers currently takes 5-7 years from lay down to commissioning.  Again, this is essentially just making better versions of what they have already built.
- On the actual physical engineering, I'm not sure that materials we currently have available would be to support such a huge mass.  The body would likely need to be entirely designed as a "wing" rather separate fuselage and wings, but this thing is going to be *heavy*.

Answer (score 2):

None of the existing answers really address the mechanical feasibility of such a thing. Firstly, it has been attempted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Nuclear_Propulsion

Then there's this, which most people think is vapourware but may actually be  a breakthrough: http://www.lockheedmartin.co.uk/us/products/compact-fusion.html

But the main problem of putting a reactor (fission or fusion) on a plane is shielding. This needs to be quite thick (many inches of lead or feet of concrete) in order to protect the crew, even if you mount the reactor at the other end of the plane from the cockpit and allow the cargo space to be irradiated. Then you need to consider how to avoid exposing ground crew to radiation as well. Let alone if you want to carry passengers. This adds to the weight of the system and makes it harder to fly.

If you have a fission reactor and don't want to irretrievably contaminate a large area of land in the event of a crash, you'll need even more weight for a containment system.

It's just about conceivable as a weapons platform if you have a lot of money and want to park a huge looming nuclear threat in someone else's sky. While it's a fun proposition as a flying cruise ship, the shielding issue would have to be solved as well as the safety issues that will probably get you banned from the airspace of all sensible countries.

Then there's the 9/11 question. If the city can fly, it can be crashed on another city. Can you secure it adequately?

Comment: Actually, I did consider shielding and it is just not that big of a problem. 20 cm of lead will stop 99.9999% of all of the reactors gamma radiation, another 20 cm will block 99.9999% that gets past the first shield. Sure it is heavy, but on the scale of a flying city it is insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

Fission? No.

Fusion? Maybe.  Lockheed Martin is working on a [compact fusion reactor](http://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/products/compact-fusion.html) that they [claim](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/531836/does-lockheed-martin-really-have-a-breakthrough-fusion-machine/) could be commercially operational in ten years.  The first link even mentions the possibility of fusion-powered aircraft.

Comment: And supposing Lockheed succeeds in years. How do you then get a flying city out of the deal in the same timeframe?

Comment: Practical fusion has been 10 years away for 30 years. To be fair though, the same was true of practical e-ink and then one day bang, there it was :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Building a craft like this is roughly equivalent to President Kennedy's statement to go to the moon**, only he's advocating that we put men on Mars by 2025:

> We choose to go to [Mars]. We choose to go to [Mars] in this decade ... not because [it is] easy, but because [it is] hard, because that goal will serve to organize and measure the best of our energies and skills, because that challenge is one that we are willing to accept, one we are unwilling to postpone, and one which we intend to win, and the others, too.

In addition to Gary Walker's answer (which is fantastic), I'll offer the following in terms of economic insight. I also recognize that I'm anchoring the size of the aircraft on "aircraft carriers".  Heck, let's just go with it.

**Mission Definition**

What is this going to do?  What will it achieve?  How large is the market?  Is that market likely to grow or shrink in the next 50 years?

For the US, it's worth the cost of multiple aircraft carriers to be able to project power anywhere on the planet. For a commercial endeavor, the investors will want a substantial return on investment.  This cannot be the "Olympics" of airplanes where billions of dollars are spent, used once then allowed to decay.  The Spruce Goose was okay only because Howard Hughes had more money than God.

**Costs of Failure**

What happens if this airship fails in mid-flight and crashes, killing everyone aboard?  How are you going to handle the liability lawsuits in event of a failure?  Would anyone insure this craft?  Probably not.

**Legislative Difficulties**

At least in the US, the FAA will have a lot to say about the regulation of this new aircraft.  New regulations will need to be developed about where it can fly, how fast, how high and for how long.  All these requirements will have an impact on the design and functionality of your craft.  Designing a craft of this size and complexity in such a dynamic engineering and regulatory environment may border on the impossible.

**Anti-terror Measures**

A craft this large could embody to poor of the earth all that is wrong with the rich elites.  As such, it will be the focus of attacks or the fear of such attacks will have a huge effect on the design and operation of this craft.  Methods will need to be developed to defeat attacks from outside the plane as well as subversion attacks by pilot or crew.  Crashing this thing into New York City would eclipse 9/11 by a large margin.

**New Powerplants**

Fission powered steam power plants are too heavy so a newer, lighter, more powerful power plant must be found.  Fusion is the better option though the Tokamak fusion reactor is a long ways off.  Other fusion methods are in development but suffer from a lack of funding.  It may take years to develop fusion power plants sufficiently powerful to lift and keep aloft for an indefinite period a craft of 100,000 tons.

Committing the funds to design a craft before there's a power plant strong enough to propel it is economic folly.  Few nations or corporations have the kind of capital to burn to indulge in such an endeavor.

**Design Precedent**

Humanity's experience with ships dates back thousands of years.  We know how to build them, how they break, what to make them out of.  Our experience with aircraft is less lengthy but such experience as we have is in a period of considerable mathematical and engineering prowess.  For a craft of this size and complexity, we have no easy analogue.

**Complexity of the Project**

As previously cited, designing a craft would take at least a decade.  In comparison, the [Boeing Dreamliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner) took the better part of decade to enter production.  The Dreamliner used new technologies in many places such as a carbon fiber wing but built on decades of development in airliner design.  Building a flying city is far outside of what we have designed and built so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible for one simple reason: what principle are you going to use to fly the the behemoth? You are most certainly not considering rotors, for it's plain impossible to fly that on rotors. The only possibility you have is jet propulsion: namely, releasing a powerful jet of steam underneath/behind to stay afloat. And with a thing weighing as much, you will need a river-worth of water supply aboard, which would actually take more space than anything else, leaving no room for anyone/anything else at all.

Answer (score -2):

The unmanned version (which saves a lot of weight from the radiation shields) is ideal to send on an intercontinental one way mission to circle over the capital city of the opponent indefinitely, broadcasting harmful pornography and nasty propaganda whilst snooping the airwaves for anything worth decrypting.  The other side might get annoyed and shoot it down, in which case they have high level radioactive waste smeared over their city.  If they don't then it will continue to circle and cause social problems and eventually dirty the fuel rods with waste products until it crash-lands, smearing their city with even more high level radioactives.  Please don't anyone build that thing.  Such may have been thought of when the US military stopped work on a 1960's nuclear ramjet which was reputedly tested with miles upon miles of closed air pipes so as to avoid any risk of release of possible radioactives in the air which passed through it.  Simple to sketch but politically and ethically horrible.

Comment: The question was "how feasible is...?" This post doesn't answer that question.